# Google reverse image search in a specific site

Tags: google-image-search, search-operators

I want to use Google (or any other good option) to search for a specific image inside a specific site.

1. I go to http://images.google.com/
2. Click on that small camera icon
3. Paste the image URL
4. Now I see a list of sites where Google found that image in.
   ([click here](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZiv1U7StU0TlKMPN30wG_1MTUh2vLu315OtWTAaq4AGYVo7QCx9WY0FhwqIgnnfJ8uzzJtVbgXjwH-Lfrlbu3Pml_1nRD-2XgJG9l9S3u7OUT7GJZeB2brzghyL5QQ67nyBjwyKCW_1YkoABPh9uwuOAMPRqb51nQtEnDB0i8Z6TsRbubSyoSVE55kI2iKGSzm0FVSnir11SeZuYqWHi8d3aAVuQVLogcMo-TXZiv1zNVhtb9Eba2-OWFYZQa9_1duXbEZj8XnUBqFhIg7y7RSQOiJ0z-QItnrMUgNJXxp7mP4SY-GExZiBZSxasCjOvdeRTcb9M5RHJ4R9JD3_1dniX5xyhth3ADpsd2aFQ9g29gJqa51d_1-KLJiiUf-g39Hjvtgn3OsuCGTe1mOTzpnkpXZfF91phyLK_1Zjx2Pqo2sxjhhgqXb5abznqEIpWIKfaLCQaoQ3BhsV1NYeTp2-39VaVjt77QIkNswT9pbUhNyLfWhWHx9u0qtsGkvqD364nWoQ_1E3PwK2mWYgaK5LQ6UWwgLyu7j_1vAJAiBULD1P6QmqcDnM4z8qG4SBH2HiduYTCdrUMUgX7Nw_1VRcHbBo0cSikGG76Px09eaJrMJABb2wkV2EVw1wQLGGmUbxi_1cuve04BAtvfEkQIRNWa7QjRNdGE_13a2YdHDdmdffxrFFHoa6QJl8Mgg2D6JWEDEUS3pUei0osY7i_13xYhUlwUwksjaEAUExdydxqmsfujtVpKTlqMWwVx1xvLtA-16PfTIgciT7pJoIHV8wNatAgF8icJe930EESLp4SkufpyIqgkgBsBcbKAUk7weYS9NtK5MgMlyE_1wV2i8EEcMqbYcIzlJ5lgL187M7AmN9RP_1zryJ_1pDUjByb52IG_1TaRxOttSKYzAEYOVVkE5K9QhqosmL9UVxsswjoMqbG1CV7-Z6vbhiR7UvS9DPUS0WqaUSMCUTFRJ1lhrYoKWBPH4zWtg-4tB98kNWu8JaqnpMU5pQMmEfK1gatNALVejiHv8yMOcplv6fvioH8vXvVmU45w9lzfhQH2tz-VPEFqMtBpEBJDiJIM1S5DjL1ZIMP4YLRwaMEHtZ4jDzvJdMwXGjs1Cjy5cJF5WQ08iXrRRHiXkyXjKQWHq_1NYCCHOBUe4WLj907INCLBXZQA8ZHK3-ksYamKVmtXGuwMqtJA0FrBts1IiN5TL0UUt46BQavxVc9oWGVXRBlOlpEOyv94BW0J65mjW4QVNpQmXVs_196jjyvgK9awgGOj9MZpDS1j7TBR3qv5ILtlnMVvob) to see my results page)

Now here's my problem:
I want Google to limit this search to a specific site (say "cnn.com" for example).
I tried using "insite:cnn.com" operator, but that doesn't seem to work when searching by image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is actually `site:`. You can add it to the search line after uploading your image.

Comment: That is the correct operator, but from my testing it seems to be ignored by Google when using reverse image search.